# SSH Server fail

Tags: server, ssh

So I installed openSSH-server on my ubuntu  16.10 with `sudo apt-get install openssh-server` and it worked BUT when I type `sudo service ssh start` it says

```
Job for ssh.service failed because the control process exited with error code. see systemctl status ssh.service and journalctl -xe for details.
```

I type `systemctl status ssh.service` and it says the following

```
`"ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell Server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code)  since 2017-01-04 15:56:11 CET; 19s ago
Process: 2701 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/sshd -D $SSHD_OPTS (code=exited, status=255)
Main PID: 2701 (code=exited, status=255)

Jan 04 15:56:11 PM-server systemd[1]: Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
Jan 04 15:56:11 PM-server systemd[1]: ssh.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a
Jan 04 15:56:11 PM-server systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Jan 04 15:56:11 PM-server systemd[1]: ssh.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jan 04 15:56:11 PM-server systemd[1]: ssh. service: Failed with result "exit-code""`
```

Any Ideas on how to fix this? I googled a couple of hours but didn't find anything usefull.
thx on beforehand.

Comment: run `sudo /usr/sbin/sshd -T` to see what is wrong with the service and why does it fail.

Comment: Unless you edited the config files, file a but report - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssh/+bug/1549473

Comment: to enable creating a SSH connection from your machine to another you do not see to install the SSH server just the client ... by installing SSH server you are enabling the world to attempt to login to your machine ... If server is needed make certain you have nailed the security else remove the server and just have the client

Comment: Maybe I should have mentioned that I'm trying to setup a SFTP-server. So I believe that I need the ssh-server or am I wrong? I'm little of a noob so what exactly am I looking for when I type `sudo /usr/sbin/sshd -T`, it looks like it shows the ssh.config file to me but I don't see the problem.

Comment: Ah, the DenverCoder95 syndrome. So. Why does `sshd` die when starting it after no configs have been modified? Makes it kind of impossible to ssh to it.